# syslog-ng equivilent of pri-test of rsyslog

Tags: rsyslog, syslog-ng

I have systems running syslog and rsyslog across my environment and I would like to have similar outputs.

I have created a template in rsyslog that looks like the following:

```
$template TraditionalFormatWithPRI,"%TIMESTAMP:::date-rfc3339% %HOSTNAME% %pri-text%:%syslogtag%%msg:::drop-last-lf%\n"
```

I would like to create something similar in syslog-ng but I cannot seem to find a replacement for `%pri-text%` which outputs the source of the message and the log level. Does anyone know if there is an equivalent in syslog-ng or if there is a combination of two template functions that I can use to create the same output?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need the ${PRIORITY} or the ${LEVEL} macros, see https://www.balabit.com/documents/syslog-ng-ose-latest-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-guide-admin/html/reference-macros.html